# WPF list does not refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

I'm trying to create a new page in a WPF application. It is an "old" project, discovering the project and the language (I know C/C++, not C# nor XAML). In that page, I have to put a list of "rapport". But I can't refresh that list with new items, nor refresh the items.

I can't put that list in XAML, I have to use a C# variable. I try a lot of things, like List, observable list, refresh, binding, trigger event from expander, so a lot of code may be useless / unreachable.

And for a precision, `piramidHandler.GetListParamReport();` has to be in the piramid class.

Thank's a lot for your help, pardon my English, still not my native language, but I try to make my best.

Rapports.xaml :

```
<Expander Header="{x:Static resx:StringResources.Lib_TabRapports}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2" IsExpanded="False" IsEnabled="True" Expanded="ExpanderRapport">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--First row for controls-->
                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="650" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="650" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ListRapports}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" Name="RapportGrid"
                  CanUserReorderColumns="False" Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}" Grid.Row="1" FrozenColumnCount="2"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="AlignBottomColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource AzureDataGridColumnHeader}" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
                        </Style>
                        <Style x:Key="RotatedColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource AzureDataGridColumnHeader}" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-4,0,0,0" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
                            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.Resources>
```

RapportViewModel.cs :

```
    public sealed partial class Piramid
        {
            internal ObservableCollection<ViewModels.Rapport> listRapports;

            public string GetRapportsList()
            {
                return piramidHandler.GetListParamReport();
            }

            public ObservableCollection<ViewModels.Rapport> ReloadRapportsLists()
            {
                var uniqueListRapport = new HashSet<ViewModels.Rapport>();
                string gabaritsXML = GetRapportsList();

           // [...] Fill uniqueListRapport

                return new ObservableCollection<ViewModels.Rapport>(uniqueListRapport.ToList());
            }
    }
public class TabRapport : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Properties
        public TabRapport()
        {

        }


        public ObservableCollection<ViewModels.Rapport> ListRapports
        {
            get
            {
                ObservableCollection<Rapport> test;
                test = Piramid.Instance.ReloadRapportsLists();
                if (test.Count == 0)
                {
                    ViewModels.Rapport current = new ViewModels.Rapport
                    {
                        IdRapport = 52,
                        NameRapport = "This is a try"
                    };
                    test.Add(current);
                    ViewModels.Rapport current2 = new ViewModels.Rapport
                    {
                        IdRapport = 54,
                        NameRapport = "Second try"
                    };
                    test.Add(current2);
                }
                return test;
            }
        }

        #endregion Properties

        #region commands

// Useless in the context

        #endregion commands
    }

    public class Rapport : ViewModelBase
    {
        public Rapport()
        {
            idRapport = -1;
        }

        public Rapport(Rapport e)
        {
            idRapport = e.IdRapport;
            nameRapport = e.NameRapport;
        }

        private int idRapport;
        private string nameRapport;

        public int IdRapport
        {
            get => idRapport;
            set => idRapport = value;
        }

        public string NameRapport
        {
            get => nameRapport;
            set => nameRapport = value;
        }
    }
```

Rapports.xaml.cs :

```
public partial class Rapports : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            OnTargetUpdated();
    }

    private void ExpanderRapport(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        OnTargetUpdated();
    }

    public Rapports()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = App.AppCultureInfo;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = App.AppCultureInfo;
    }

    public void OnTargetUpdated()
    {
        RapportsRoot.Reload();
        RapportGrid.Items.Refresh();
    }

    public void OnTargetUpdated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        RapportsRoot.Reload();
        RapportGrid.Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

EDIT :

DataContext : `DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=OngletRapport}">`

Reference to :

```
public TabRapport OngletRapport
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<TabRapport>();
            }
        }
```

EDIT 2 : Added code in the RapportViewModel.cs. My current try just show "This is a try" and "second try" as a list, not able to change it after setting data in listRapport

Comment: Where do you create an instance of `RapportViewModel` or `Piramid` and/or set the `DataContext` for `Rapports`?

Comment: Edited to answer. Pirapid is a low level class, so not really usefull to answer (and not simple for me !).

Comment: Is ListRapports in xaml backed by a ListRapports in VM to bind to?  I only see listRapports.

Comment: Do you always try to change/refresh the list by using the `ReloadRapportList()` procedure? If so, then your issue is creating always new instances. Observable collection is made so that you update the contents of the collection, and then the List can effectively react on those changes through notifications.

Comment: I try using `.Reload()` and also `.Refresh()`, that's why I let the two of them in my message. But none of them make new elements of my list appear. With breakpoints, I also can tell that `.Refresh()` get access to a `get` of an attribute of `Rapport`, but never access to the `get` of the listRapport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally find the answer.

I need to use `ObservableObject.RaisePropertyChanged("ListRapports");` at the end of all background traitement, forcing the listRapports to refresh all data and items number.

Thank's a lot for all your help :)